# Using md5 to generate unique id for CSS style

Tags: php, html, css, md5

I am trying to generate a unique id for a div so that I can style it accordingly per page.  Everything seems to be working great but my css selector is not recognizing the md5 id. For this specific page I am working on the id generated is 749dd97038.  So my question is why is the CSS not taking the id, is it because the way md5 works, will it not work like this?  If not what is a better solution then using md5?  Many thanks.

My PHP code

```
<div id="sub-header" class="layout-<?php echo WpvTemplates::get_layout() ?> <?php if(!empty($page_header_bg) || !empty($global_page_header_bg)) echo 'has-background' ?>">
<div class="meta-header" id="<?php echo substr(md5($page_header_bg), 0, 10) ?>" style="<?php echo $page_header_bg ?>">
    <div class="limit-wrapper">
        <div class="meta-header-inside">
            <?php
                WpvTemplates::breadcrumbs();
                WpvTemplates::page_header(false, $title);
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS code

```
#749dd97038.meta-header {
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: 50% calc(50% - 250px) !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
    height: 321px !important;
}
```

And the HTML looks like this

```
    <div class="meta-header" id="749dd97038" style="background-image:url('http://wabi-sabi-opal-philosophy.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;">
    <div class="limit-wrapper">
        <div class="meta-header-inside">
            <header class="page-header ">
            <div class="page-header-content">
                <h1 style="">
                <span class="title">Family Therapy+Support</span>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </header>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By adding a prefix such as "a" the css now recognizes it allowing me to style it.

Comment: So for those who might run into the same problem this fixed it for me <div class="meta-header" id="<?php echo 'a', substr(md5($page_header_bg), 0, 10)?>" style="<?php echo $page_header_bg ?>">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the CSS documentation (highlighting by me):

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **they cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

MD5 is obviously not a good choice for identifiers (and it makes reading and maintaining the code a horrible exercise). I assume your variable `$page_header_bg` contains unwanted characters like spaces, so I'd write a function that cleans this up:

```
function createSlug($name) {
    $name = strtolower($name);
    $name = str_replace(array('ä','ö','ü','ß'), array('ae','oe','ue','ss'), $name);
    $name = preg_replace("/([\W]+)/", "-", $name);
    return trim($name, '-');
}
```

This is a function I use for cases like this (you can remove the line that handles german umlauts). It reduces all non-word characters in a string to a single hyphen and returns a lower case identifier without spaces, dots etc.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond had to go to bed, your spot on with your css I feel like I should of known that, I got it to work by just adding a prefix infront of the md5 and now it works, I still would like to figure out your way too.  Im just not sure how it would work, I can just put that function in my php tag and change $name to $page_header_bg?  Sorry new to php.

Comment: You just call it instead of your `substr(md5())`: `<?php echo createSlug($page_header_bg); ?>` (and of course use the result in the .css file)

Comment: When I use your function it makes the id="background-image-url-http-www-mywebsite-com-clients-opal-wp-content-uploads-2011-10-12-jpg-background-repeat-no-repeat", so its returning the location of the image I am trying to style and the inline styling of that image, is there any way to make the id a smaller string?